# why my file input multiply and send the same image twice?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

so i have this ajax script to shown the image that the admin send to client but i have problem is that everytime the admin upload new image the script keep doubleing and send image twice for example if the admin upload first image it shown one image and the admin add a new image <-- and here the problem start it double the image that being upload (now it sending the same image twice and so on) how can i fix this? i don't know if my backend is the problem or my ajax script, here is my code and thank you.

my ajax script

```
$("#btn-file-input").on("click",function(){
    $("#file-input").trigger("click");
    $('#file-input').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var form = new FormData();
        var dat = $('#file-input').prop('files')[0];
        console.log(dat)
        form.append("image-user",dat);
        form.append("id_user",id_user);
        for(var q of form.entries()){
            console.log(q[0]+ ', ' + q[1]);
        }
        $.ajax({
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "updateimage",
            data: form,
            success: function(result) {
                var result_json = JSON.parse(result)
                console.log(result_json)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

my backend

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def admin_send_image(request):
        data_ajax_r = request.FILES.get('image-user')
        id_user = request.POST.get('id_user')
        user = UserMessage.objects.get(line_id=id_user)
        admin_now = Account.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        file_storage = FileSystemStorage()
        file_storage.save(data_ajax_r.name,data_ajax_r)
        url_object = file_storage.url(data_ajax_r.name)
        url_to_line ='https://c93c90ff8ee8.ap.ngrok.io'+url_object
        line_bot_api.push_message(user.line_id,[ImageSendMessage(url_to_line,url_to_line)])
        ctx = {"admin_name":admin_now.username,"file_name":url_object,"admin_image":"/media/"+str(admin_now.gambar)}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx))
```

here is screen shot of the problem in my website;

first image uploaded in chat

[image: first image]

second image uploaded and shown the problem

[image: second image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a change event handler every time `#btn-file-input` is clicked. You should only add this event handler once, unless you have some specific reason to add the event handler inside another event handler you should move it outside.

```
$("#btn-file-input").on("click",function(){
    $("#file-input").trigger("click");
});
$('#file-input').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var form = new FormData();
    var dat = $('#file-input').prop('files')[0];
    console.log(dat)
    form.append("image-user",dat);
    form.append("id_user",id_user);
    for(var q of form.entries()){
        console.log(q[0]+ ', ' + q[1]);
    }
    $.ajax({
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "updateimage",
        data: form,
        success: function(result) {
            var result_json = JSON.parse(result)
            console.log(result_json)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ohh i get it i first though that if the input is trigger i need to put the event change in the same handler  to get the val of the input thanks dude it really help!!.